# Apache Mod Rewrite Resulting in err::TOO MANY REDIRECTS with HTTP request

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm using the following .htaccess file in my /api folder on my server:

I'm merely making an http request to a url http://www.example.io/api/[resource]. However, I keep getting a *too many redirects* error.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /api/


# If requested resource exists as a file or directory go to it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule (.*) - [L]

# Else rewrite requests for non-existent resources to /index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?request=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

All I wish to do is redirect to the index file and append the `[resource]` to the parameter "request" if the folders and directories do not exist. Help!

Comment: I don't think you need that leading slash before `index.php...`. Perhaps the redirects are coming from your app? Have you checked the network tab of your browser console?

Comment: But there are no redirects happening here only internal rewrites. Do you have any other .htaccess or any rule in Apache config